# For a matrix group $G$ of dimension $d$, I am trying to prove that the function $Ad : G \rightarrow GL_d(\mathbb{R})$ is smooth.

Tags: matrices, lie-algebras

For a matrix group $G$ of dimension $d$, I am trying to prove that the function $Ad : G \rightarrow GL_d(\mathbb{R})$ is smooth. So where I am starting is by extending $Ad : G \rightarrow GL_d(\mathbb{R})$ to $Ad : GL_d(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow GL_d(\mathbb{R})$, which if I can show is smooth will let me know that the former is smooth. And from my text I know that $Ad_g(B) = gBg^{-1}$ So if i replace B with $E_{ij}$ as a standard basis. I can show that from cramers rule, that all entries will be rational. Am I on the right track?

Comment: You are trying too hard.  Do you know the formula for the inverse matrix?

Comment: do you mean the formula that is $A^{-1} = 1/det(A) \times (cofactor of A)^T$

Comment: Yes. Now think if this is a smooth function of A.

Comment: Oh, I think I see. From this equation I see that every element of the matrix A, has a denominator of $1/det(A)$ which gives us that there is a rational function, which means that it would be smooth.

Comment: Good. Now, you can answer your own question and accept your own answer.